# Issues Importing Obj Files Into Maya

Tags: python, object, import, scripting, maya

Thanks for taking a moment to read this! So, as the title of my post implies, I'm trying to import some obj files into Maya, but I get the following error message when I try running my script:

```
Error: line 1: TypeError: file <maya console> line 8: object of type 
'NoneType' has no len()
```

My script is listed below:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds


pathOfFiles = "/This PC/Desktop/Facial Rigging Blendshapes/"
fileType = "obj"

files = cmds.getFileList(folder=pathOfFiles, filespec='*.%s' % fileType)
if len(files) == 0:
    cmds.warning("No files found")
else:
    for f in files:
        cmds.file(pathOfFiles + f, i=True)
```

Thanks again for taking the time to read this! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the path. If `cmds.getFileList()` get's a non existing path, it returns `None`, not an empty list. So I suggest to check if the directory exists or check for `None` result. I can reproduce your problem if use this code:

```
pathOfFiles = "C:/Userss"
files = cmds.getFileList(folder=pathOfFiles)
```

Where "C:/Userss" does not exist.

Comment: Thank you so much! I replaced "This PC" with "Users/Owner" and all of the obj files were able to be imported in without a problem. Thanks again for saving me from my own stupidity! Cheers!

Comment: OP, you should mark this answer as accepted so people who google it know it's the right one